# Google Chrome - focus on recently edited snippet window

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, code-snippets

I often use Google Chrome Snippets panel for creating JS scripts. While I run command "Run snippet" (ctrl + enter), cursor goes to the Chrome console window and I must click back in snippet, to write more code. This is very inconvenient.

The question is - how goes back from Console window into the snippet, without using mouse, maybe with single shortcut?

I find, that I can use ctrl + p shortcut (find file), but this is not correct solution. Every time, I must type the name of my snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the right answer.
In Chrome settings select "Enable Ctrl + 1-9 shortcut to switch panels".

After this, you can run ctrl + enter to execute snippet code and after this, focus back in snippet using ctrl + 3.